# Jenkins gives error for private git repository

Tags: jenkins, github

I can access public repos thru Jenkins, But when I try to access private Repos,

I get error:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

I have copied the public key of the jenkins server to Github SSH/ deploy keys, also copied the Private key to the Jenkins using SSH with username and password method, Why is this causing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you see an HTTPS URL, all your SSH keys won't help much.

You must use an SSH URL for your private repo, in order for Jenkins to use SSH keys successfully:

```
git@github.com:<auser>/arepo
```

The [OP Nishad Nazar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248483/nishad-nazar) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428959/jenkins-gives-error-for-private-git-repository/55441220#comment97635532_55441220):

> `git pull` wasn't working. It now works: I changed the `git pull` URL to Git pull `https://username:password@github.com/owner/repo`.
>   Now it works and pull the changes from Git via Jenkins.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this too, but still its the same error. What is auser? Is that the username used for login or the name of the organisation, For example, If my github repos is under https://github.com/xp/app.git, then Shud I give, git@github.com:xp/app.git or git@github.com/username/app.git?

Comment: @NishadNazar auser is the name of the owner of the repo.

Comment: Thnx for connecting with me, I have edited my query a bit

Comment: Again, even after giving the owner/repo I get the same error. Basically, I need to pull the changes of git to my server, So If I give git status in the shell execute script in jenkins, it works fine, server has proper access to the git and  git status is executed, but If i give git pull, i get the could not read username error in jenkins.

Comment: @NishadNazar Do you still get an error including an HTTPS URL?

Comment: Yes actually, I get this: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address, But Git status works fine, but Git pull execution under Jenkins gives error, How do I pull changes from github via Jenkins.

Comment: @NishadNazar As long as you see an HTTPS URL, something in wrong in your config. For SSH keys to work, you need to use an SSH URL. Check your Jenkins job configuration: is there an HTTPS URL *anywhere* in that config?

Comment: I have given only SSH URL in the repository URL space. And it works previously too. But git pull wasn't working. It now works, I changed the git pull to Git pull Https://username:password@github.com/owner/repo, now it works and pull the changes from git via Jenkins..thanks for Ur speedy support

Comment: @NishadNazar Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.